# Reducing SVG length continuously on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am trying to make an scrolling animation where as you scroll, the x2 point of a svg line will be 50% of the value before it.

Let's say that you start at x2 = 100, you do a `onscroll` function and then you would have an `x2 = 50, 25, 12.5...` etc.

As you scroll, the line will shrink less and less quickly.

This is what I have so far:

```
<body onscroll="myFunction()">
  <svg id=l ine height="50" width="100%">
    <line id = horLine x1="0" y1="0" x2="100%" y2="0" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
    </svg>
</body>
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    ( ? ? ? )
  }
```

I don't know what the JavaScript for this would be.

I assume I should create a variable and then have it halve that variable value every time the function runs.

I cannot seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery:

```js
var x2 = $('#horLine').attr('x2').slice(0, -1);
// .slice(0, -1) is used to remove the '%' from the attribute

$(document).scroll(function () {
    x2 *= 0.99;
    $('#horLine').attr('x2', x2 + '%');
});;
```

```css
svg { position: fixed;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg id="line" height="50" width="100%">
<line id="horLine" x1="0" y1="0" x2="100%" y2="0" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
</svg>
<div style="height: 1000000px;">
</div>
```

I didn't do 50%, but 99%, so you can see the effect.

You can improve the behavior by detecting scroll up / down etc.

Comment: Assuming he is using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

If the x2 is a percent it is a little more complex, but you can get the element by id then set it based on the current value of x2.

So you function would be like this:

```
var x2 = document.getElementById("horLine").getAttribute("x2").match(/\d+/)[0] / 2 + "%";
document.getElementById("horLine").setAttribute("x2", x2);
```

You could also use `subtring` instead of `match` to remove the percent sign. Not sure which is more efficient.